# How do I convert a CSS background-position property from percentages into pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-image

I'm centering a background right now (using `background-position: 50% 50%;`), that I'd like to animate using Javascript. But, I want to be able to animate this using pixel measurements. Effectively I want to set the background-position to something like "50% + 10px". Is this possible using Javascript?

I can possibly do it by finding the height of the background image and the height of the browser screen and do some arithmetic, but this seems like a convoluted solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the future this will be possible using CSS3's [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc) function. But since that's not widely supported right now, below is a more practical solution.

Simply use the [incremental notation jQuery supports](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties) for these properties. For example

```
$(some-element).css({ "background-position": "+=10px" });
```

This syntax was supported by $.animate before it was supported by $.css, but recent versions of jQuery support it in both cases.

[Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/g7mSk/).

Comment: The only problem I have here is that I need that 50% as a reference point. I'd be animating the background image to a position of 50% + x pixels, where x = some number I calculate. And I'd be doing this many many times. (I mean... I guess I could just calculate the delta number but that won't be as accurate as I'd like.)

How does jQuery implement this kind of thing internally?

Comment: @EdD I traced it down as far as jQuery's [`curCSS` function](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=_curCSS) which seems to indicate it uses [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3Awindow.getComputedStyle).